# Getting error while creating ekscluster with the same name

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created ekscluster with a name called "prod". I worked on this "prod" cluster after that i have deleted it. I have deleted all its associated vpc, interfaces, security groups everything. But if i try to create the ekscluster with the same name "prod" am getting this below error. Can you please help me on this issue?

```
[centos@ip-172-31-23-128 ~]$ eksctl create cluster --name prod
--region us-east-2 [ℹ] eksctl version 0.13.0 [ℹ] using region us-east-2 [ℹ] setting availability zones to [us-east-2b us-east-2c us-east-2a] [ℹ] subnets for us-east-2b - public:192.168.0.0/19 private:192.168.96.0/19 [ℹ] subnets for us-east-2c - public:192.168.32.0/19 private:192.168.128.0/19 [ℹ] subnets for us-east-2a - public:192.168.64.0/19 private:192.168.160.0/19 [ℹ] nodegroup "ng-1902b9c1" will use "ami-080fbb09ee2d4d3fa" [AmazonLinux2/1.14] [ℹ] using Kubernetes version 1.14 [ℹ] creating EKS cluster "prod" in "us-east-2" region with un-managed nodes [ℹ] will create 2 separate CloudFormation stacks for cluster itself and the initial nodegroup [ℹ] if you encounter any issues, check CloudFormation console or try 'eksctl utils describe-stacks
--region=us-east-2 --cluster=prod' [ℹ] CloudWatch logging will not be enabled for cluster "prod" in "us-east-2" [ℹ] you can enable it with 'eksctl utils update-cluster-logging --region=us-east-2
--cluster=prod' [ℹ] Kubernetes API endpoint access will use default of {publicAccess=true, privateAccess=false} for cluster "prod" in "us-east-2" [ℹ] 2 sequential tasks: { create cluster control plane "prod", create nodegroup "ng-1902b9c1" } [ℹ] building cluster stack "eksctl-prod-cluster" [ℹ] 1 error(s) occurred and cluster hasn't been created properly, you may wish to check CloudFormation console [ℹ] to cleanup resources, run 'eksctl delete cluster --region=us-east-2
--name=prod' [✖] creating CloudFormation stack "eksctl-prod-cluster": AlreadyExistsException: Stack [eksctl-prod-cluster] already exists status code: 400, request id: 49258141-e03a-42af-ba8a-3fef9176063e Error: failed to create cluster "prod"
```

Comment: Have you tried to recreate the "prod" cluster right after you deleted it? Or did you wait a bit?

Comment: i have tried in both ways

Answer (score 2):

There are two things to consider here.

1. The `delete` command does not wait for all the resources to actually be gone. You should add the `--wait` flag in order to let it finish. It usually it takes around 10-15 mins.
2. If that is still not enough you should make sure that you delete the `CloudFormation` object. It would look something like this (adjust the naming):

   `#delete cluster:
   -delete cloudformation stack
   aws cloudformation list-stacks --query StackSummaries[].StackName
   aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name worker-node-stack
   aws eks delete-cluster --name EKStestcluster`

Please let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this error while Running EKS via Terraform - I'll share my solution hopefully it will save other some valuable time.

I tried to follow the references below but same result.

Also I tried to setup different [timeouts](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#timeouts) for delete and create - still didn't help.

Finally I was able to resolve this when I changed the `create_before_destroy` value inside the [lifecycle](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/eks_node_group#ignoring-changes-to-desired-size) block to *false*:

```
  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
```

(*) Notice - pods are still running on cluster during the update.

---

References:

[Non-default node_group name breaks node group version upgrade](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/862)

[Changing tags causes node groups to be replaced](https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-eks/issues/843)